# AddDbContextPool does not work with Azure Ad authentication for Azure SQL

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-managed-identity

I followed MS documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi) to configure Azure AD managed identity for Azure SQL authentication, which involves adjusting connection string (remove username/password) and adding these codes to DbContext's constructor:

```
var conn = (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection();
conn.AccessToken = (new Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
```

It works fine with the standard `services.AddDbContext()` method in Startup.cs. But as soon as I use `services.AddDbContextPool()` for higher performance, the authentication breaks with the following error:

SqlException: Login failed for user ''.
Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)

Is this a known limitation of `AddDbContextPool()`?

Comment: @thankyousd Have you managed to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @utvecklare It turns out the pool just won't work with constructor based token pattern because the constructor is called just once. I switched to using the `DbConnectionInterceptor` pattern. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/azure-identity-with-sql-graph-ef/#ef-core-integration